# Target numbered classes with *

Tags: joomla-3.x, css, hikashop

I have a list of prices which automatically increment the class, for example the first one is called '.hikashop_product_price_0' and all others are then _1, _2 etc...

I want to be able to hide all of the prices apart from the first one, I've tried something like the following but it's not working:

```
.hikashop_product_price.hikashop_product_price_* {display: none;}
.hikashop_product_price.hikashop_product_price_0 {display: block;}
```

The HTML Markup looks something like:

```
<div class="hikashop_product_price_full hikashop_product_several_prices">
    <span content="33.96" itemprop="price" class="hikashop_product_price hikashop_product_price_0">£ 28.30</span>
    <span class="hikashop_product_price_per_unit"> each</span>
    <br>
    <span content="43.188" itemprop="price" class="hikashop_product_price hikashop_product_price_1">£ 35.99</span>
    <span class="hikashop_product_price_per_unit"> each</span>
    <br>
    <span content="41.316" itemprop="price" class="hikashop_product_price hikashop_product_price_2">£ 34.43</span>
    <span class="hikashop_product_price_per_unit"> each</span>
    <br>
    <span content="52.068" itemprop="price" class="hikashop_product_price hikashop_product_price_3">£ 43.39</span>
    <span class="hikashop_product_price_per_unit"> each</span>
    <br>
    <span content="49.956" itemprop="price" class="hikashop_product_price hikashop_product_price_4">£ 41.63</span>
    <span class="hikashop_product_price_per_unit"> each</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add the HTML markup please? Not all of it, just just the first few lines

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zx2cqp5w/ ?

Comment: Yes, looking at similar to the jsfiddle, but want to hide all of the items apart from 'hikashop_product_price_0'

Comment: So like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zx2cqp5w/2/

Comment: I've added the HTML markup above, as they're not shown as list items

Comment: Are you not able to wrap the span tags in a `div`?

Comment: I found this on Stack OverFlow 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes)  It looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple as that:
just correct your own rule to be like this

```
.hikashop_product_price {display: none;}
.hikashop_product_price.hikashop_product_price_0 {display: block;}
```

so first selector hides everything
and second shows your specific item